# How to loop through multiple polymorphic models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I don't know how to make a loop that goes through 2 models apart of the polymorphic association I have. I have the models `User`, `Follow`, `Dad` and `Mom`.

```
class User
 has_many :follows
end

class Mom
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
  # columns: name, :address
end

class Dad
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
  # columns: name
end

class Follow
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
 # columns: user_id, followable_id, followable_type
end
```

My goal is to loop through the moms and dads that the user is following and get there specific attributes like this:

```
# FollowsController

index
 # follows = dads and moms
 @follows = current_user.follows.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

# follows/index.html.erb

<% @follows.each do |f| %>
 <%= f.dad.name %>
 <%= f.mom.name %>
 <%= f.mom.address %>
<% end %>
```

How would this be done?

Comment: each iteration you have either a dad relation or a mom relation, never both at once.... how about <%= f.dad.name if f.followable_type == "Dad"? %>

Comment: @SteveTurczyn So theirs no real way to put both in a feed?

Comment: Does the current_user have many dads and moms?  If so, are the dads and moms related to each other or linked somehow?

Comment: Maybe what you need is a Family record, each family has both a mom and a dad?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Was trying to avoid more models. I think Ahmad gave me what I was looking for. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use

```
f.followable.name
f.followable.address
```

If you want to check if it is dad or mom then you can check it like this

```
f.followable_type == 'Dad'
```

Or

```
f.followable.kind_of?(Dad)
```